# Query for search from string

Tags: mysql

I have name values like "Kevin Peter", "John Doe", "Michael Jag".

I want to write a query that can search either by first name or last name of the string.

For example, searching by "J" should yield John Doe & Michael Jag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` keyword alongside the MySQL wildcard `%`

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'J%' OR name LIKE '% J%';`

Comment: This is assuming all names are stored as "FirstName LastName" with no other possible spaces.  If this is still too naive of an implementation based on the data, I'd suggest researching RegEx in MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: I think this is a MySql question based on the tags...more relevant link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: @BarbiePylon - Thanks.  I had noticed that as well and updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%J%';
```

<strike>Would be what you need. Check the like function out [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).</strike>

**Edit:** This is obviously the wrong answer.

Why don't you store it as "firstname" and "lastname" instead? There is no easy way to determine what the firstname is.

Comment: Well, this could return something like `FOOJAR BAZ` and if he only wants the first or last name to start with the `J`, then it doesn't quite work.

Comment: @EricHotinger Absolutely right. I'm afraid I was a little too fast with my answer. Thanks for noticing!